# ExtJs - How can I put a colorPicker inside a combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

How can I put a `colorPicker` (`Ext.picker.Color` - which contains a predefined set of colors) inside a `combobox` and see that the selected color appears in the `textfield` of the `combobox`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this, is to create your own input field, which is derived from [`Ext.form.field.Picker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html).

For this, it is necessary to implement the method [`createPicker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html#method-createPicker). There you can create and return an instance of [`Ext.picker.Color`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.picker.Color.html).

Here is an example to clarify the basic idea:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.color.Field', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',

    requires: [
        'Ext.picker.Color'
    ],

    createPicker: function () {
        return Ext.create('Ext.picker.Color', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.ux.color.Field', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

In the next step, the values of the two components must also be connected to one another. The corresponding events of the components can be used for this purpose.

Here is a simple example of the possible end result:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/228f

[image]

Comment: Thanks Artem.. I have placed the custom field in the form by aliasing it as         alias: 'widget.gmColorField' .It is allowing me to select one of the color fields from the dropdown .But the background color is not being set right.It is just showing a single line of color  at the bottom of the field as opposed to coloring the whole textfield.. Any ideas on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: @surfIsUp My fiddle should work with ExtJs >= 5.0. Which version do you use? Can you provide a fiddle with the error?

Comment: `var pickerMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.ColorPicker', {
        listeners: {
            select: function (picker, selColor) {
               alert(selColor);
            }
        }

  });

 Ext.define('Ext.MyButton', {
        extend: 'Ext.Button',
        menu: pickerMenu, // menu
        alias: 'widget.menuButton',
        text: 'Please pick a background color',
  }); `

Comment: I have used the  code mentioned in the comment earlier for the color picker .With the code in the answer, the `colorpicker` is not always below the  `combobox`. Thats why i have tried doing it differently as mentioned above and it's working.

Answer (score -3):

There are plenty of javascript color pickers around.
Just add one of them to your page and make the "magic thing" to put all toghether.
See this example : [Bootstrap Color Picker sample](https://farbelous.github.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/)

Comment: I am sorry this wouldn't workout for me as i am working in ExtJs and I also want just the `colorPicker` predefined colors in the dropdown of the combobox